# Usar sentencia IN en CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una query que trae el listado de empleados segun una jerarquia, en donde G es gerencia, S supervisor, Id el emplado.:

```
SELECT Id, Nombre, Apellido, Correo,Cargo, Jerarquia
FROM Empleados
WHERE Estado = 1
   AND Jerarquia like 'G-S-Id%'
```

Hasta aqui todo bien, la idea de la query es que los empleados puedan ver el listado de los mismos, segun el rango de jerarquia que posean (Ej: Jerarquia "G-S", podra ver todos los usuarios bajo un supervisor)

El detalle ahora, es que me pidieron que, solo para ja jerarquia "G-S", debo incluir un par de usuarios... Trate de hacer un case, pero no me funciono y no se que estoy haciendo mal:

```
SELECT Id, Nombre, Apellido, Correo,Cargo, Jerarquia
FROM Empleados
WHERE Estado = 1
   AND Jerarquia like '@Jerarquia%'
   or CASE Jerarquia
      WHEN 'G-S' THEN (Id in (1310, 1151, 798, 229)) END
```

En resumen, si la Jerarquia es 'G-S', hay que incluir los Id's que aparecen ahi, caso contrario, no incluir nada.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas usar una sentencia case para resolver el problema. Si le das una vuelta de tuerca al planteamiento del problema, lo que necesitas es al resultado de la consulta *normal* agregarle los empleados x, y, z, solo cuando la jerarquía es 'G-S'.

Si tratamos de acercarnos a la lógica formal, traduciríamos esto en tu consulta original (con todas sus condiciones) OR (las nuevas condiciones para agregar empleados).

En SQL, luciría algo como:

```
SELECT Id, Nombre, Apellido, Correo,Cargo, Jerarquia
  FROM Empleados
 WHERE (    Estado = 1
        AND Jerarquia like @Jerarquia + '%'
       )
    OR (     @Jerarquia = 'G-S'
        and  Id in (1310, 1151, 798, 229)
       )
```

Debes tomar en cuenta la precedencia de los operadores lógicos, por claridad adicional estoy poniendo entre paréntesis todas las condiciones de la consulta *normal*, luego `OR` y las nuevas condiciones también entre paréntesis. Esto puede no ser necesario y, si estás seguro de mantener la lógica, puedes quitar los paréntesis que consideres que están de más ya en tu consulta real. (En este caso se podrían quitar todos).

Comment: Te pasaste! Excelente respuesta y muy clara, entendi a la perfeccion. Con esto puedo aplicarlo a otras logicas, ya que pensaba siempre que para este tipo de condiciones era mejor emplear sentencias case.